# Adding click event to every polygon on map in leaflet to use map.fitBounds()

Tags: leaflet, javascript

Here is my code. But it's showing only last polygon which is iterated from array. (For binding polygon I am using array)

```
var polygon, i;
for (i = 0; i <= latlngs.length; i++)
{
    if (i < 2) {
        polygon = L.polygon(latlngs[i], { color: 'green' }).addTo(mymap);
    }
    else {
        polygon = L.polygon(latlngs[i], { color: 'red' }).addTo(mymap);
    }
    polygon.on('click', function (e) {
     mymap.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
    });       
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are reassigning the `polygon` variable at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
var polygon, i;
for (i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {

    if (i < 2) {
        polygon = L.polygon(latlngs[i][0], { color: 'green', id : latlngs[i][1]}).addTo(mymap);
    }
    else {
        polygon = L.polygon(latlngs[i], { color: 'red', id: latlngs[i][1] }).addTo(mymap);
    }

    polygon.on('click', function () {
        //mymap.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
        mymap.fitBounds(this.getBounds());

        getChilds(this.options.id);
    });
```

Comment: if i<2, shouldn't it be point.

Comment: No .. i have posted answer..